# 'alphanet.sh head' returns old block

Tags: tezos-client, alphanet

I'm using the docker-based version and when running `alphanet.sh head` it reports:

```
[...]
"hash": "BMFjnKKcGVwuNKfdS8BWX8kVbj8JTKea112FXTbZvPmh8CbQ1h5",
[...]
```

This block is from more than 6 months ago:
https://alphanet.tzscan.io/BMFjnKKcGVwuNKfdS8BWX8kVbj8JTKea112FXTbZvPmh8CbQ1h5

Why is it stuck in the past?

Trying the same command a few minutes later still yields the same block.

**Update** When running
`tezos-client activate account alice with tz1.json` it starts validating blocks:

```
Current head: BKyWLsqeybrZ (timestamp: 2018-12-10T06:15:18-00:00, validation: 2019-06-30T14:16:11-00:00)
Current head: BMKw9TdLNNpw (timestamp: 2018-12-10T06:15:48-00:00, validation: 2019-06-30T14:16:11-00:00)
Current head: BLFj7cuVmqdn (timestamp: 2018-12-10T06:16:18-00:00, validation: 2019-06-30T14:16:12-00:00)
Current head: BMRawWof8Pk1 (timestamp: 2018-12-10T06:16:48-00:00, validation: 2019-06-30T14:16:12-00:00)
Current head: BLherdvJRv3q (timestamp: 2018-12-10T06:17:18-00:00, validation: 2019-06-30T14:16:12-00:00)
Current head: BM4Gqiq6hihp (timestamp: 2018-12-10T06:17:48-00:00, validation: 2019-06-30T14:16:12-00:00)
[...]
```

To reach today's date it would take about 20 hours on my machine. Can this be accelerated? Given that this is for experimentation, I'de fine with not verifying everything back till genesis.

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrapping a whole chain is a quite long process depending on your network bandwidth and hardware power but also on the number of peers participating in the network and, of course, the length of the chain. After running a node for the first time, it can take a few seconds/minutes to gather a minimal number of peers in order to start receiving some blocks.

If you don't want to validate the whole chain from the genesis, you can use the storage snapshot feature. For short, it allows you to import the chain using a single, and rather small, file.

Documentation about storage snapshots can be found here: http://tezos.gitlab.io/mainnet/user/snapshots.html

Snapshots files of all the Tezos networks can be exchanged thanks to the community.

Comment: Thanks. For this to be practical, a snapshot file is required. For mainnet I see some files at https://www.tzdutch.com/quicksync/, but is there a similar source for alphanet?